# return a row from a 2d-array with the max value in a specific column (ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix, row

For that matter I created a matrix to find the requested row:

```
require 'matrix'

m = Matrix[['IPE', '80', 2], ['HEB', '100', 1]]

index_of_specific_row = m.index(m.column(2).max)[0]

puts m.row(index_of specific_row)

#==> Vector['IPE', '80', 2]    # row with the max value of the third column
```

Now I'm looking for an equivalent solution without matrix.
But I'm stuck here:

```
array = [['IPE', '80', 2], ['HEB', '100', 1]]

array.find { |row| row == max_value_of_the_third_column }
```

I can't figure out `max_value_of_the_third_column`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array = [['IPE', '80', 2], ['HEB', '100', 9],['HHB', '100', 6]]
array.max_by(&:last) #=> ["HEB", "100", 9]
```

***Update:(`How do I select a specific column (number_of_column instead of last)?`***

```
array = [['IPE', '80', 2], ['HEB', '100', 9],['HHB', '200', 6]]
p array.max_by{|i| i[1].to_i} #=>["HEB", "100", 9]
array = [['IPE', '80', 2], ['KEB', '100', 9],['HHB', '200', 6]]
p array.max_by{|i| i[0]} #=>["HEB", "100", 9] #=> ["KEB", "100", 9]
```

Comment: @ericMTR this solution is far better then mine, you should choose this.

Comment: @toro2k Thanks for your appreciation! :)

Comment: @Priti It looks promising but assuming I've got more values. How do I select a specific column (`number_of_column` instead of `last`)?

Answer (score 1):

You could map `array` to get an `Array` of the third elements from subarrays and then use the `max` method:

```
array = [['IPE', '80', 2], ['HEB', '100', 1]]
max_value_of_the_third_column = array.map { |a| a[2] }.max
array.find { |a| a[2] == max_value_of_the_third_column }
```